# Defining global struct array of pointers

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04

im learning c programing.
I want to define a global struct array of. so I would have a pointer to that array that each member of the array is a struct of complex numbers. 
**my goal is to be able to acces to this array by his pointer (*vars) and being able to change/read its members on every function at the main.**

Im facing troubles with this issue and im not sure how and where to define each thing.
I tried this next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct complext
{
    double real;
    double img;
} complex;
complex* vars;

int main()
{
    int i;
    vars = malloc(6 * sizeof(vars));
    for (i = 0; i < 6;)
        vars[i]->real = 0;
}
```

Im getting an error when im trying to acces vars[i].
"request for member 'real' im something not a structure or a union.
Thanks!

Comment: You should typecast the return value of `malloc`. As so: `vars = (var*)malloc(6 * sizeof(*vars));`. Also, you should change the last line to `vars[i].real = 0;`.

Comment: No, don't cast when it's not necessary.
Sorry, my comment was in answer to Shiva's.

Comment: Tried that but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Shiva [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). This is a C question, not in C++.

Comment: @ncarrier My bad. I meant to cast it to `(*vars)`, not `(*complex)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 bugs in your code
1. `vars[i]->real` should be `vars[i].real`. Pls honor the **data-types** You have defined `vars` to be a global pointer to the `complex` structure. To define it as an array use: `complex vars[6];`  --> Look at @José Fonte 's ans
2. `malloc` returns a `void *` cast it to `(complex*)`  --> I learnt this should be ok (look at comments posted by @Stargateur)
3. The `for` loop at the end has no inc statement for `i` hence it runs forever
4. The `malloc` only allocates 6 pointer worth of memory (which is 6*sizeof(int)) since `vars` is a pointer of type complex.  `sizeof(vars)` should be `sizeof(complex)` --> @xing pointed this out

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

typedef struct complext {
double real;
double img;
}complex;
complex *vars;

int main()
{
int i;
vars= (complex*)malloc(6*sizeof(complex));
for(i=0;i<6; i++)
vars[i].real=0;
}
```

Comment: I agree with 1 and 3, not with 2.
And as Shiva has spotted, `sizeof(*vars)` should be used instead of `sizeof(vars)`

Comment: 2. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @xing: Thanks for pointing it out! overlooked it - corrected now

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing pointers with arrays. Doing it as an array (as a pointer already done by @Zakir):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

typedef struct complext {
   double real;
   double img;
}complex;
complex vars[6];

int main()
{
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<6;i++)
   vars[i].real=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vars is of type `struct complext *`, but vars[i] is of type `struct complext`, so you just have to use `vars[i].real` instead of `vars[i]->real`.